# How can I generate a DKIM signature for my domain when using a vendor's mailgun account?

Tags: mailgun

We work with a company that uses mailgun to send emails from their software.
This then causes emails sent from mailgun to look like they are coming from our organization, parksville.ca.

Do I have to create our own mailgun account in order to be able to generate a DKIM signature so we can ensure the the DMARC is properly reporting mailgun email as being valid for our domain?

Or should the vendor that is using mailgun provide us with this?

Thanks,